# Symfony, using path() (javascript) in a twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, routes, twig

In my javascript, I need to use a route. In the Symfony's documentation, it said that I can include my script in the twig to get the route BUT my route needs a parameter, then I found

```
var isbn = 1234567890;
var url = {{ path('book_search_general', {'isbn': 'isbn'}) }};
url.replace("isbn", isbn);
```

But javascript believes that it is a regular expression.
In the HTML source code it's:

```
var url = /public/book/isbn;
url.replace("isbn", isbn);
```

An I have the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

Comment: Try `/abc/.exec('abc')` in a Javascript console, then look closely at `var url = /public/book/isbn;`. Hint, it think's `/public/` is a regular expression. (See: [pattern enclosed between slashes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#creating_a_regular_expression)). Another hint: quotes are needed in the template.

Comment: I'm not trying to write a regular expression, I'm trying to get the routing of my service and I don't know how to say it between the javascript and the twig :(

Comment: Yes, add quotes around the `{{ ... }}`. Like `'{{ path(...) }}'`. Whether you like it or not, `path()` doesn't quote itself so you have to add them yourself. Or Javascript will read it as `/public/` is a regex, and the rest is invalid flags.

Comment: Thank you, it works with the quotes